# Class with a field of type Nullable<private struct> causes C2248 error

Tags: c#, c++-cli

There is C# library which is used from c++/cli code. In the library is a class which contains a private field of type Nullable, where Struct is private to the class. When any method of such class is accessed from c++/cli code there is a compilation error:

```
2>cliuse.cpp(5): error C2248: 'csstruct::Foo::MyStruct': cannot access private class declared in class 'csstruct::Foo'
2>  cliuse.cpp(5): note: see reference to class generic instantiation 'System::Nullable<csstruct::Foo::MyStruct>' being compiled
2>  cliuse.cpp(5): note: This diagnostic occurred while importing type 'csstruct::Foo ' from assembly 'csstruct, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

The error does not happen if `struct` changed to `class` (so that I don't have to use Nullable), and this is how it was fixed, but it feels like not right if such subtle detail affect the design, and if there is a way to resolve it without changing the library it would be very nice to know it.

The code (simplified):

C# library:

```
using System;
namespace csstruct
{
    public class Foo
    {
        public static Foo Instance() { return new Foo() { myStruct = null }; }
        public void Bar() { Console.Out.WriteLine("Bar: {0}", this.myStruct); }
        private Nullable<MyStruct> myStruct;
        private struct MyStruct
        {

        }
    }
}
```

c++/cli code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace System;
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    auto obj = csstruct::Foo::Instance();
    obj->Bar();
}
```

Comment: Yet another compiler bug to add to the already large collection :)